# Read line from notepad with VB application and submit information

Tags: vb.net, browser, refresh, notepad

So I recently created a script that logs into various websites, such as Twitter, Xbox, YouTube, and it checks to see when "usernames" are free'd. Most of these social networking service's after so long, delete inactive accounts and allow these accounts to be claimed. So a user who has the username "John391" can get the username "John" as long as it is inactive, then the network will release it. So my script logs into these websites, and allows you to enter in a textbox which username you want, and then you click submit. The program constantly tries to claim it for when it becomes available. BUT, instead of using a textbox, I want to use a notepad with lists, so like this:

```
John
Achilles
Richard
Logan
```

and so after it tries to claim John (and if John is still unavailable), it then goes to Achilles and so on. So here's my script so far, I have a timer, and a button that do most of the work. The timer is what is used to constantly check what's in the textbox value over and over, and the button just gets the process started. I also must mention, that when I first started doing this my program continued to time out, I found out the only way to fix that was to pause the claiming and refresh the page, but this is fine. Anyways, let me explain my script:

```
   Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick



    If Not number_of_ticks > NumericUpDown1.Value Then
        number_of_ticks += 1
        If ((WebBrowser1.IsBusy)) Then
        Else
            If WebBrowser1.Url.ToString = "https://live.xbox.com/en-US/ChangeGamertag" Then


                WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("NewGamertag").SetAttribute("value", txtTurbo.Text)

                WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("claimIt").InvokeMember("Click")
            Else

                WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://live.xbox.com/en-US/ChangeGamertag")


            End If
        End If

    Else
        'number_of_ticks has exceed the maximum amount of allowed ticks
        Timer1.Enabled = False
        WebBrowser1.Refresh()

        number_of_ticks = 0
        Timer1.Enabled = True



    End If



End Sub
```

As you can see here's the timer, it checks the number_of_ticks to determine when the page should refresh. This is set by the whoever uses the program as well. Usually it is at 250, so it tries to claim until 250, then refreshes. It also has a little bit of protection, I've noticed it will render the program unresponsive if it tries to claim when the page hasn't loaded, so I've thrown in a couple if statements to fix that. And of course, the button just has the command of enabling the timer to work & some other minor functions.

Now, what I am trying to do, is instead of using the Textbox txtTurbo to allow what's claimed over and over, I want a notepad to have a list of what to be claimed. So I understand that the value of this will be changed somehow:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("NewGamertag").SetAttribute("value", txtTurbo.Text)
```

And it will be made into streaming a notepad/txt file to read which ones to claim, and after every claim it should change to the next line of the notepad/txt file. However, I have no experience with reading from text files and I didn't know it was possible till about a month ago. I was wondering if anyone could lead me in the right direction?

Comment: I'm confused :P Do you just want to read from a text file?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to read from a text file this is a good method. I created 4 different string (val1-4) and I read all the lines in a test text file that I made (Testt.txt). Then assigned the values of the text file to the corresponding strings

```
Dim val1 As String
Dim val2 As String
Dim val3 As String
Dim val4 As String

Dim lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:/testt.txt")
val1 = lines(0)
val2 = lines(1)
val3 = lines(2)
val4 = lines(3)
```

In your case val1 will equal to **John** , val2 will equal to **Achilles** and so on..